# How to send the number of models inside a collection, from Nodejs and Express, over to Backbone

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express

I use nodejs and express for my js server.

I need a way to fetch the number of models inside a collection and send it to Backbone.

The express side is rather straight forward:

```
db.books.count(function (err, booksNr) {

    if (err) return;

    console.log(booksNr)

    res.json(booksNr);

});
```

But how do i send this over to backbone?

My first thought was to bing the **booksNr** to a collection, but I can't make it work.

Here is how I fetch a collection from Backbone:

```
books.fetch(
    {
        data: {

            'fetchType' : 'list',

            'currentPage': 1, 

            'perPage': 3 
        },

        success: function(books) {

            console.log(books);

            var books = books.models;

            var template = _.template(listBooksTpl, {

                books : books, 

            });

            setTimeout(function () {

                that.$el.html(template);

                $(that.preLoader).hide();

                that.$el.show('slow');

            }, 500);    

        },

        error: function() {

            console.log("BookList error!");
        }
    }
);
```

Here is how I send the collection data to Backbone:

```
exports.books.paginated = function (req, res) {

    var currentPage = parseInt(req.query.currentPage - 1),

        perPage = parseInt(req.query.perPage),

        skip = parseInt(currentPage * perPage);

    db.books.find({}).limit(perPage).skip(skip, function (err, books) {

        if (err) return;

        res.send(books);
    });
};
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite simple, you need an api for retrieving books, in express.js:

```
app.get('/api/books', function(req, res){
    var query = createQueryFromReq(req);
    BookModel.find(query).exec(function(err, books) {
      res.send(books);
    });
});
```

Then you need a Books Backbone.Collection in your client side, notice that it does the parsing automatically, **you don't need to add your own success parser**:

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var Books = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Book,
    url: "/api/books",
});
// Some main.js 
var myBooks = new Books();
myBooks.fetch({
    data: {/* your data */},
    reset: true // Trigger reset in backbone 1.0+  
});
```

Now, you should listen to `"reset"` event fired on myBooks and act upon it

**After Comments**:

The need is to be able to paginate from the server, I would recommend using https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator

if you want to use your own solution, you could be using this approach, on the Server side supply the extra information:

```
app.get('/api/books', function(req, res){
    var limit = req.params.limit;
    var offset = req.params.offset; 
    var bookCount = getBookCount(); // how many books we have
    BookModel.find(query).skip(offset).limit(limit).exec(function(err, books) {
      res.send({
         limit: limit,
         offset: offset,
         total: bookCount,
         books:books,
      });
    });
});
```

On the Client side you should use the parse function on Books:

```
var Books = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Book,
    url: "/api/books",
    parse: function(response){
         this.total = response.total;
         this.offset = this.offset + this.books.length; // I would test this line :) it might need a -1 also here
         return response.books; // only using the books part of the response to create the models
    }
});
```

Now you need to keep track on your limit and offset, and in the first time you fetch use data give it offset zero:

myBooks.fetch({
        data: {offset:0, limit:10},
    });

Another alternative it to have this Collection part of a Paginator Model, (but you can just use backbone.paginator for this)

Comment: Ty for helping, the problem is I just need to retrieve the books number, not the whole collection - since it will be hard on the client if , let's say, the collection has 1 mil books:)

Comment: So what I did, is used a model without an id, added custom data so express will recognize the get request... from express I just sent the books number - which I can store as a vriable to that view. I'm not sure this is good practice though... maybe you cna take a look.

Comment: @DanyD - why don't you send the book ids (only the book ids)? I can edit my answer to match it...

Comment: @ ekeren I want to avoid pulling allot of data at once - having big collections in mind - this way, If I know the total number, I can paginate on the server side, and get , for example - parts of the collection which would contain 10 models.

Comment: @DanyD - ok, got it... will try to offer another solution, hope it will fit your needs

Answer (score -1):

Upon more research, here is how I did it...

Is this a good way to go?

**Is it a good practice to fet a model without an ID?**

In Backbone, I instantiate a model without any id:

```
// Random model - get total number of books.

book = new Book();

// Get the total number of books.

book.fetch({

    data : { 'fetchType' : 'booksNr' },

    success : function (booksNr) {

        that.booksNr = booksNr.get('booksNr');
    }, 

    error : function () {

        console.log("Error! Failed to get the total number of books.");
    }
});
```

In express, I look for the query string: fetchType and do the following:

```
exports.books.paginated = function (req, res) {

    var fetchType = req.query.fetchType;

    if (fetchType == 'booksNr') {

        db.books.count(function (err, booksNr) {

            if (err) return;

            res.json({ 'booksNr' : booksNr });

        });

    }
};
```